# Cant get to edit lightning Rich Text component

Tags: richtextarea

I added a lightning rich text component that I would like to use to make logs/notes of a record(custom object).

However, when in the app I only see this component displayed on the application, but cant get to edit this.

Am I missing something here?
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details : Are you referring to the std Lightning Rich text component or a custom lightning component ? are you adding this in a lightning record page?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that teh lightning component 'Rich Text' is display only and that I will need to create a new custom input rich text area. Thanks